# How to design frequency polygons in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot frequency polygons based on the following: vector

```
x: c(48, 30, 35, 31, 21, 28, 34, 43, 36, 45, ,41, 33, 47, 47, 30, 47, 44, 45, 32, 46, 47, 23, 30, 23, 49, 20, 24, 20, 40, 50)
```

And the sample command is:

```
plot(x, y, type = "b", main = "DoThi", sub = "X", xlab = "Tuoi", ylab = "TS")
```

The difficulty is that I can't figure out how the variable y comes into being. Can anyone help me create a variable y to look like the picture. Thanks

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3PGd.png)

Comment: Where did you get the code from, if you don't have a vector `y` and don't know where it comes from?

Answer (score 2):

Picking up on @Berhard's comment that you may be looking for the frequency, i.e. count of the values in the vector `x`; and adding trillion units of measure to the x axis:

Alternatively if you don't want scientific notation but text try `xlab = "Tuoi [Trillions]"`

```r
x <-  c(48, 30, 35, 31, 21, 28, 34, 43, 36, 45, 41, 33, 47, 47, 30, 47, 44, 45, 32, 46, 47, 23, 30, 23, 49, 20, 24, 20, 40, 50)

#frequency count for the x vector
df <- data.frame(table(x))

# create a dataframe which includes the complete integer sequence
# between minimum and maximum values which will be merged with the
# original data. The merge create `NAs` where the original data has
# missing `x` values. After the merge `NAs` are substituted by 0.
 
df1 <- data.frame(x = min(x):max(x))

# add frequency of 0 for missing integer values within the x vector range

df <- merge(df1, df, all = TRUE)

df$Freq[is.na(df$Freq)] <- 0 

plot(df, type = "l", main = "DoThi", xlab = expression(Tuoi~"["*x*10^{12}*"]"), ylab = "TS", col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The variable y is interpreted as the number of occurrences of the numbers in the variable x, such as how many times in the range 20-25 occur and I try a lot but can't draw like my pattern. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Perhaps you want a histogram where the number of occurrences are counted by bins? What is it in the answer that is different from your expected pattern? Is it that start and finish of the line is at y = zero?

Comment: Yes and I tried a lot but still not as expected

Comment: Not clear what you tried but maybe you want `hist(x)`?

Comment: By the way can you tell me how to add the units of column x like trillions written on the chart. Thank you very much

Comment: Updated answer, does this work for you now?

Comment: +1 as I like how you added those `0` values to the plot even though it remains unclear, what the OP actually wants. This makes your answer better then mine.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)

x <-  c(48, 30, 35, 31, 21, 28, 34, 43, 36, 45, 41, 33, 47, 47, 30, 47, 44, 45, 32, 46, 47, 23, 30, 23, 49, 20, 24, 20, 40, 50)

id <- 1:length(x)

df <-
  tibble(
    x = x,
    id = id
  ) 

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(id,x))+
  geom_line(col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question in a different way then @Peter. I understand `y` as being the counts of `x` as in

```
x <- c(48, 30, 35, 31, 21, 28, 34, 43, 36, 45, 41, 33, 47, 47, 30,
       47, 44, 45, 32, 46, 47, 23, 30, 23, 49, 20, 24, 20, 40, 50)
x_coord <- sort(unique(x))
y_coord <- as.integer(table(x))
plot(x_coord, y_coord, type = "b", ylim = c(0,5))
```

[image: Counts of x values]

Comment: Thank you very much